# OpenCart проверка является ли страница product-ом

Tags: opencart

Подскажите, существует ли какой-то способ/метод проверить в header.tpl, footer.tpl является ли текущая страница product-ом? Например: `if (is_product) { // do something }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->request->request['route'] // = product/product
```